# TCP/IP Port stops listening all of sudden

Tags: c#, tcp, port

**Little Background**

I have a Windows service (written in C# .NET) that listens on several different ports using TcpListener. some of the ports are (8090, 8091, 554, 25100, 25101).
Each port listener performs different tasks which I'm not going to mention in detail here in this question.
The service keeps on running OK for weeks without any trouble and then all of sudden one of the port 8091 stops receiving new client connections. However other ports remain functioning OK and so as the windows service.

**How this port (8091) is being used**

User can access the Windows service port from the browser using a secure HTTPS URL. For example look at this URL.

https://XYZServer.net:8091/ABC/?access=123

In the Windows Service I am opening this port using TCPListner. Some sample code is written below.

```
m_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8091);
m_listener.Start();

m_listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(DoAcceptWebTcpClientCallback, m_listener);
```

And then when a new client connection request comes in. See some sample code.

```
private void DoAcceptWebTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = m_listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);

                var webConnection = CreateConnection(client, m_waitForDeviceTimeout);
                webConnection.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                s_log.Error(ex, "{0}: Exception", m_serverName);
            }

            try
            {
                BeginAccept();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                s_log.Error(ex, "{0}: Exception", m_serverName);
            }
        }
```

I am associating the sslStream with the client connection. Also I am authenticating the Server using a certificate without authenticating the client. Sample code below

```
protected override WebConnection CreateConnection(TcpClient client, int waitForFb4Timeout)
        {
            return new HttpsConnection(SERVER_NAME, client, m_serverCertificate, waitForFb4Timeout); // Create an ssl/tls connection using the configured certificate
        }

public HttpsConnection(string serverName, TcpClient client, X509Certificate serverCertificate, int waitForFb4Timeout) : 
            base (serverName, client, GetStream(client, serverCertificate), DeviceConnection.ProtocolEnum.HTTP, waitForFb4Timeout)
        {
        }

        private static Stream GetStream(TcpClient client, X509Certificate serverCertificate)
        {
            // Create the SslStream using the client's network stream.
            var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);

            // Authenticate the server but don't require the client to authenticate.
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);

            return sslStream;
        }
```

Windows service relays all the messages coming on this port to another destination (a WebSocker Server) and relays the response back to the browser. User can then see the page on the screen. This keeps on working fine for weeks and then all of sudden users can't browse the page and new client connection requests on the port 8091 stops coming.

When this happens, no exceptions are raised. It is really annoying and hard to understand whats really going wrong here..

One more thing I would like to mention that in the same windows service we are making lots of outbound connections which is using ephemperal port range (49000-65535). I can see all of these ports beings used and then reused again and again. However there are no evidence of all the ports being used at once. I know that there are ways to increase the port range but I have not tried this yet as I'm not convinced that we are reaching to the limit.

I can see several exceptions in the code related to authentication on this port.

```
2018-08-11 01:39:43.8952|ERROR|Fb4RelayServerLib.WebConnections.WebServer.DoAcceptWebTcpClientCallback: HTTPS: Exception System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

People have suggested on different forums about using

```
SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Whereas I am only using the SslProtocols.Tls only (see code). I have not tried above as in my case I am getting this exception rarely and for the same client IP which is also working fine.

I'm really stuck and don't know how to troubleshoot and further investigate this issue. Any help in this regard will be very helpful. Many thanks in advance and sorry for a lengthy question.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Right, after a lot of struggle I finally resolve the issue.

I did two things mainly to address the problem.

1- Add the support for tls1.1 and tls1.2 which my product was lacking originally. (As I posted in my question as well)

2- Replace AuthenticateAsServer with AuthenticateAsserverAsync.

Actually for some unknown reason the AuthenticateAsServer function was hanging and not allowing the application to accept any new client connections.

Doing above changes, it seems to be working fine so far. Keeping my fingers crossed :)